# How to create a macro with arbitrary parentheses which are asymetrical (not paired)

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, ffi, lispworks

I want to define a macro which encapsulates the frequent pattern below.
The code is for FLI of lispworks.

```
(fli:with-foreign-string ;; class name pointer
 (cn-p ec bc :external-format (external-format)) "BUTTON"
 (fli:with-foreign-string ;; window name pointer
  (wn-p ec bc :external-format (external-format)) "Configuartion:server"
  (let ((grpbx (createwindowex 0 cn-p wn-p
                               (logior ws_visible ws_child bs_groupbox)
                               0 0 300 420 hwnd 1 (GetModuleHandle-current 0) 0)))
    (fli:with-foreign-string ;; class name pointer
     (cn-p ec bc :external-format (external-format)) "EDIT"
     (fli:with-foreign-string ;; window name pointer
      (wn-p ec bc :external-format (external-format)) "192.168.200.200"
      (createwindowex 0 cn-p wn-p
                      (logior ws_visible ws_child ws_border)
                      10 30 150 30 hwnd 1 (GetModuleHandle-current 0) 0)
      )))))
```

The macro I want to create is something like below:
THe **strs** parameter is a list of strings, e.g. **("BUTTON" "Configuartion:server")** above,
**str-syms** accumulates the converted strings which will be fed to **createwindowex**.
What confused me was that the strings to be used **(cn-p and wn-p)** are in the middle of the body,
and I had to split the body into 2 parts: **part-bdy** and **&body bdy.**

But the problem is **part-bdy**, which is first part of **LET** block (before **createwindowex**), has many parentheses,
whose counter parts are only in the send part **(&body bdy)**.
Which means the parentheses in **part-bdy** are not open and cause error when evaluated.
Do you have any clever idea to advise me to solve it?

```
(defmacro with-foreign-string (strs str-syms part-bdy &body bdy)
  (let ((g (gensym)))
    (if (null strs)
        (append part-bdy str-syms bdy)
      `(fli:with-foreign-string
        (,g ec bc :external-format (external-format)) ,(car strs)
        (with-foreign-string ,(cdr strs) ,(cons g str-syms) ,part-bdy ,@bdy)))))
```

Comment: A macro manipulates code, not parentheses. Could you add some detail, e.g. give a small, but complete example? Thanks.

Comment: You seem to be trying to insert your generated symbols in the middle of the body. You should instead let the user provide the symbols with a `LET`-like construct `(with-foreign-strings ((class-name "BUTTON") (window-name "...")) ... (createwindowx 0 class-name window-name ...))`

Answer (score 2):

Just want to share that I changed the macro as below:

```
(defmacro with-foreign-str (strs str-syms bdy)
    (if (null strs)
    bdy
      `(let ((,(car str-syms) (gensym)))
      (fli:with-foreign-string
    (,(car str-syms) ec bc :external-format (external-format)) ,(car strs)
    (with-foreign-str ,(cdr strs) ,(cdr str-syms) ,bdy)))))
```

then the code code above without using the macro can be rewritten like this:

```
  (WITH-FOREIGN-STR ("BUTTON" "Configuartion: server") (cn-p wn-p)
    (let ((grpbx (createwindowex 0 cn-p wn-p
                 (logior ws_visible ws_child bs_groupbox)
                 0 0 300 420 hwnd 1 (GetModuleHandle-current 0) 0)))
          (WITH-FOREIGN-STR ("EDIT" "192.168.200.95") (cn-p3 wn-p3) 
               (createwindowex 0 cn-p3 wn-p3
                               (logior ws_visible ws_child ws_border)
               10 30 150 30 hwnd 1 (GetModuleHandle-current 0) 0))))
```

This is still not so clean but anyway I can manage to simplify the code using macro.
There were not so many responses only because I think due to the FLI and win32 API in the code.